# I need to set uitableviewCell backgroundColor based on observed property. How do I dynamically set specific row?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I need to set uitableviewCell backgroundColor based on an observed property. How do I dynamically set the row to be grey or white in the observed method, unless there is a better method to implement in.

I am observing whether the object is valid, at which point i make the cell active (white) or not (grey).

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the cell for a particular row using

```
  UITableViewCell *cell = [YourTableVIew cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:YourROW inSection:YourSection];
```

Comment: So i get the cell and just set its property that way? do i need to redraw the table? how does that work?

Comment: if you do it this way then no redraw is needed ... however to redraw you can call `[tableview reloadData]`..in that case all the change you want to do should be in the cellforRow method .